# can a windows service be spawned from something other than services.exe?

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-xp-sp3

in the `_EPROCESS` structure, the `Inherited From Unique Process` field for services like `alg.exe`,`svchost.exe`,`spoolsv.exe` always points to `services.exe`. So, here are my questions.
1) Can a service be spawned from non-`services.exe` process
2) Can `services.exe` spawn a non *service* process?

Comment: Are you having problems getting your services started?

Answer (score 0):

Services.exe is the service control manager, so it is likely that it starts all services, but this is probably not guaranteed. It is also probably not guaranteed the services.exe doesn't spawn other processes. In fact it seems likely that it might.

Perhaps if you said why you want to know, we might be able to help with the wider problem.